# How to choose random words once from a list in a .txt file (VB)

Tags: button, random, cpu-word, label, text-files

I have a .txt file full of 5 letter words which I need picking in a random order, but just once per word. I want these words to show in a label and then be changed every time i press a button. Thanks in advance.

I'm using VB, sorry about not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want this script on a html page, using either front-end scripting (javascript) or back-end scripting (php).

Either way you should to the following.

- Read the text-file and convert it to a string
- Use a string-to-array function like split() in javascript or explode() in PHP
- generate a random number between 0 and the amount of rows in your array
- echo the array row matching the generated number (php) or assign the array row to the label.innerHTML (js)

I'm sorry I can't give you the exact code right now, might write it for you tonight.
Do you want to make it on JS or PHP?

Comment: no i want it in a program and i'm not the best programmer, so i do need a little more help than usual